# Path to file in Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have path to file defined as `String caFilePath = "/your_ssl/ca.crt";` in Eclipse Java project that runs on Windows.

Can't figure out where this folder should be located. I was trying to add it to many places, but program doesn't find it while run in IDE. Where it should be located?

UPD:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
   String caFilePath = "/your_ssl/ca.crt";
   SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory(caFilePath,
                    clientCrtFilePath, clientKeyFilePath, "");
...
}
```

Comment: Mostly in the `resources` folder.

Comment: That depends on how `caFilePath` is being used (please show the code). One thing that's certain is this can't be a valid file system path on Win - I may be wrong :)

Comment: Placing in `resources` not helped. I have updated question body with code

Comment: In the code snippet you only see that `caFilePath` is passed to the method `getSocketFactory`. If `caFilePath` is a file path, then the folder must be located in the root directory (because `/your_ssl/ca.crt` starts with `/`), e.g. if running on `C:` it is `C:\your_ssl\ca.crt`. However, it is recommended to use relative (not starting with `/`) instead of absolute file paths.

Comment: Are you getting a `FileNotFoundException` or a `NullPointerException`? If yes, then [edit] your question and post the stack trace.